# How to get ID off Onclick Button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cart

I want to get a button onclick ID and apply it to another function.

```
<input type="button" onclick="recordToFilename();" id="submitdis" value="Enter Discount Price" />
```

And Apply it to

```
document.getElementById('discounts').innerHTML = "Discount : $" + ( - discountprice).toFixed(2);
```

Please check [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEhmD?editors=101)

Thanks for help

```
   document.getElementById("submitdis")
   function recordToFilename() {
   var input = document.getElementById('submitdis'),
   discount12 = input.value;
```

Comment: inline javascript functions are bad practice. Stick with `element.addEventListener("click", function(e) { console.log(e.target.id) })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing argument to your onclick function

```
<input type="button" onclick="recordToFilename(this);" id="submitdis" value="Enter Discount Price" /> 


 function recordToFilename(ele)
 {
       console.log(ele.id);
 }
```

Comment: Would you mind testing it in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Drsxg?editors=101) I am just brain dead right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function recordToFilename(e){
   $(this).attr("Id")

  //or:
   e.Id
}
```

Comment: for $(this), you need to import jquery file too.

Comment: I assume he has that already, standard asp.net web application includes jquery library. Edit: although he never says that he has not imported the jquery script

Comment: but the OP hasn't tagged jQuery in the question

Comment: True, Also if you inspect his codepen link. You will get $ undefined. So, just for his clarity. Never mind

Comment: Alright then, to clarify: if you import the jquery library u might try that. I did not look at ur codeExample and i did not look at the tags either so i made a mistake. regardless if you ever want to try it with jquery this might be a possible soloution

Comment: I would like to use jquery but I am using this for an offline application on the ipad. I am still having trouble . I am researching more basic javascript thanks [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEhmD?editors=101)